# How to access a file a path level below from a subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, credentials

Let's say I have a file called `credentials.json` in my current directory, an environment variable `MY_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json` and a script `main.py` that uses this environment variable via `os.getenv('MY_CREDENTIALS')`.

Now suppose I create a subfolder and put something there like this: `/subfolder/my_other_script.py`.
If I print `os.getenv('MY_CREDENTIALS')` then I get indeed `credentials.json` but I can't use this file as it is in my root directory (not in `/subfolder`). So, how can I use this file although it is in the root directory? The only thing that works for me is to make a copy of `credentials.json` in `/subfolder`, but then I would have multiple copies of this file and I don't want that.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: Why not set the environment variable to the absolute path?

Comment: @bluesummers because I need to deploy this to the cloud while keeping my Dockerfile and YAML as simple as possible.

Comment: by YAML I believe you mean the docker-compose file, so if you tell a little bit more about the use case, it will be easier to help

Comment: Can't you put a directory in the variable `MY_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json`?  Put a different (perhaps relative) path when developing, and a hard absolute path in the production Docker instance.

Comment: @tripleee If I copy the absolute path of the credentials it would give me something like this: `/home/user/Desktop/myproject/credentials.json` and then I can use this perfectly in `my_other_script.py`. But if I copy the relative path, I get simply `credentials.json` and then I have problems because the subfolder can't access this file.

Comment: You don't have to switch your working directory to `subfolder` even if that's where the script lives. `python ./subfolder/my_other_script.py` should run it just fine. If the script needs to find its own directory, use `sys.argv[0]` or just pass another configuration option for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

FILENAME = os.getenv('MY_CREDENTIALS')
filePath = Path(FILENAME)

if filePath.exists() and filePath.is_file():
    print("Success: File exists")
    print(filePath.read_text())
else:
    print("Error: File does not exist. Getting file from level below.")
    print((filePath.absolute().parent.parent / filePath.name).read_text())
```

Basically, you check whether your file exists in the current folder. This will be the case, if your script is in your root folder. If it is not, you assume that you are in a subfolder. So you try to get the file from one level below (your root).
It's not totally production ready, but for the specific case you mentioned it should work. In production you should think about cases where you might have nested subfolder or your file is missing for good.

Answer (score -1):

You can create symbolic link

```
os.symlink('<root>', '<subfolder>')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am not sure how to use this.